# How do I build dialect sensitive SQL queries with the following data using JOOQ or any other library?

Tags: java, relational-database, query-builder, querydsl, jooq

I have a list of strings that are to be part of the `SQL Select` statement as columns. And another list of strings which represent the tables that are to be joined in the `SQL` query.

```
List<String> columns = Arrays.asList("sakila.actor.first_name", "sakila.city.city",
        "sakila.category.category_id");
List<String> tables = Arrays.asList("actor", "film_actor", "film", "inventory", "store",
        "address", "city", "country", "film_category", "category");
```

The JOIN ON condition is represented in an XML like the following.

```
<join type="inner" operator="=">
<!-- type can be right or left or full also -->
    <left table="rental" column="staff_id"/>
    <right table="staff" column="staff_id"/>
</join>
```

I have unmarshalled the XML and I have list of custom Join objects representing the above XML.

With the help these lists I have created SQL select statement. But the query is not compatible with MySQL in some cases and Postgres in another case. I want to support all databases. How can I build such queries using JOOQ with this kind of lists mostly Strings? or In fact any other good library? I am just interested in the String that represents the SQL and I don't have to execute it immediately.

I was trying to use `JOOQ` but it seems I need to learn a bit about its API. Any example for my use-case will also be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any answer hinges largely on what you mean by "the query is not compatible with MySQL in some cases and Postgres in another case". Most queries built by jOOQ will run fine across different databases, unless you're using database-specific functionality. By your brief example, you're not doing that, fortunately.

To directly answer your question: You can easily turn your XML "ON" condition into a Condition object with the data you have available. In jOOQ's API, it would look something like (assuming you have a DSLContext object called `create`):

```
Condition joinCondition = fieldByName(leftTable, leftColumn).eq(fieldByName(rightTable, rightColumn));
create.select(columns)
    .from(tableByName(leftTable))
    .join(tableByName(rightTable))
    .on(joinCondition)
    .fetch();
```

You can alternatively use the Query syntax, which might work better for your dynamic queries:

```
SelectQuery selectQuery = create.selectQuery();
selectQuery.addSelect(selectFields);
selectQuery.addFrom(leftTable);
selectQuery.addJoin(rightTable, joinCondition);
```

You'll need to iterate your columns array and convert them to fields with this API. That might look something like:

```
List<Field<?>> fieldColumns = new ArrayList();
for (String column : columns) fieldColumns.add(fieldByName(column.split('.')));
```

Good luck! jOOQ is fantastic.